# Zend Framework 2 Custom validator

Tags: zend-framework2

I have created my custom validator by extending Identical and just returning:

```
!parent::isValid($value)
```

I have created my own library `cb/Validator` and have included this in the include path; however, when I run the application I get an error saying:

> cb\Validator\Identical Class not found.

Does anyone know how to access a class from the main library from your own library?

My validator is as below:

```
<?php
namespace cb\Validator;
use Zend\Validator;

class NotIdentical extends Identical
{
    public function isValid($value)
    {
        return !parent::isValid($value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use statement should be as follows:

`use Zend\Validator\Identical;`

You are importing classes with the `use` statement and not namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fully qualified name of Zend's Identical validator:

```
class NotIdentical extends \Zend\Validator\Identical
```